# How to require ES module with node -r options

Tags: node.js, command-line-interface, es6-modules, preload

In some case I need to start a node.js process with the `-r` option to preload a ESM library `mriya`. The library can be installed with the command `npm i mriya`, and the command I want to run is `node -r mriya`. It works when I require a CommonJS module, but when it is a ES module the command will fail with the following message

```
[Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module mriya-test/node_modules/mriya/dist/mriya.js not supported.
Instead change the require of mriya.js in null to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.] {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Is there alternative option for `-r` to use with the ES Module, or is there any workaround I can use? Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```bash
node --experimental-loader your-esm-module
```

https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html#loaders

---

You can omit `experimental-` too:

```
node --loader your-esm-module
```

---

Also, see:

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/40110

https://github.com/nodejs/node/issues/44094

https://github.com/nodejs/node/pull/43942

Comment: Finally we got this.